# Can I cite my accepted but not yet presented conference paper?

Tags: publications, citations, conference, proceedings

My paper has been accepted for an IEEE international conference coming in September (2 months from now), and I have successfully registered for the conference (so would be presenting it then).

By the conference rules, only papers presented at the conference by one of the authors (registered) would be published and therefore appear in the proceedings.

Going by this rule, is it OK to cite this paper in a work I'm doing currently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, cite it. Note that the form of citation probably isn't critical at the submission stage. By the time the final version of the new paper is being written the conference citation will become fixed. It takes more than two months from submission to final version preparation in the best cases.

Depend on the delay and on the fact that edits will almost certainly be required before acceptance. Give enough in the citation so that the reviewer isn't confused or worried about plagiarism, but the final form can wait.